# How to correctly read a C-string into a Fortran string of unspecified length?

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

The following function is supposed to convert a C string into a Fortran string and works fine in Release builds, but not in Debug:

```
! Helper function to generate a Fortran string from a C char pointer
function get_string(c_pointer) result(f_string)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(c_ptr), intent(in)         :: c_pointer
    character(len=:), allocatable   :: f_string

    integer(c_size_t)               :: l_str
    character(len=:), pointer       :: f_ptr

    interface
        function c_strlen(str_ptr) bind ( C, name = "strlen" ) result(len)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), value      :: str_ptr
            integer(kind=c_size_t)  :: len
        end function c_strlen
    end interface

    l_str = c_strlen(c_pointer)
    call c_f_pointer(c_pointer, f_ptr)

    f_string = f_ptr(1:l_str)
end function get_string
```

However, it seems that [`c_f_pointer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fF_005fPOINTER.html) does not tell the Fortran pointer-to-string, `f_ptr`, the length of the string it is pointing to. In Debug builds, where bounds-checking is active, this results in

```
Fortran runtime error: Substring out of bounds: upper bound (35) of 'f_ptr' exceeds string length (0)
```

I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0` and set the standard to 2008.

**My question: Is there any way to tell the `f_ptr` its length without changing the declaration or am I doing something fundamentally the wrong way here?**

---

It seems to run correctly if I specify the shape, but for that `f_ptr` needs to be an array:

```
character(len=:), allocatable   :: f_string
character(len=1), dimension(:), pointer :: f_ptr
...
call c_f_pointer(c_pointer, f_ptr, [l_str])
```

However, I cannot find a way to transform that string of rank 1 to the `character(len=:), allocatable :: f_string`, which apparently has rank 0.

**My second question: Is there any way to transfer the `f_ptr` data into the `f_string` in this example?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `c_f_pointer` to set the length of the Fortran character pointer (F2018, 18.2.3.3):

> FPTR shall be a pointer, shall not have a deferred type parameter [...]

A deferred-length character scalar (or array) therefore cannot be used (the length is a type parameter).

You can indeed use a deferred-*shape* character array as `fptr` and then use any [number of techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980844/3157076) to copy the elements of that array to the scalar (which is rank-0 as noted).

For example, with substring assignment (after explicitly allocating the deferred-length scalar):

```
allocate (character(l_str) :: f_string)
do i=1,l_str
  f_string(i:i)=fptr(i)
end
```

Or consider whether you can simply use the character array instead of making a copy to a scalar.

Comment: Possibly, is it also valid to use a fixed-length character string (within a block) like... `l_str = c_strlen(c_pointer); block; character(len=l_str), pointer :: f_ptr; call c_f_pointer(c_pointer, f_ptr); f_string = f_ptr; end block`?

Comment: Yes, @roygvib, that would be possible.

Comment: thanks! (I'm also preparing similar helper routines so looking at available codes)

Comment: @roygvib, I'm not sure I like that approach, but I wouldn't be able to tell you why. I'd let it through review, but I'd probably be more demanding of comments than I would with some alternatives. Perhaps the reason it jars a touch is that, if you have a C array of characters it's more natural for the intermediate Fortran object also to be an array of characters rather than a storage associated scalar (both then being thrown away).

Comment: @roygvib, or maybe it's that you can't do `block; character(len=l_str), pointer :: p1, p2; call c_f_pointer(cptr, p1); call c_f_pointer(cptr, p2); end block` (because you can't have two such Fortran character pointers pointing to the same C target).

Comment: Yes, that must be why I don't like it. You get used to this approach, then one day you find yourself using it in a similar way where you aren't actually allowed to and your spaceship blows up.

Comment: thanks very much for additional comments! Actually I also have a bit "uneasy" feeling about the code (in my comment above), though it seems to work with gfortran (for example). My another concern is that I might hit some varying behaviors depending on compilers (incl. issues), so I think I will go with the usual approach of first creating a temporary character array, then copying to a deferred-length string (after allocating with the right length). thanks much :)